# question about concurrency code from oracle.com that explains Deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I got a cross a piece of code from oracle.com which explains concurrency in general and deadlock in particular. the code is from :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html

I tried hard to understand what is going on and what causes the deadlock here through debugging and manually running the code, but for no avail.

I would be very thankful if someone could break the flow of this code and explain why and where the code gets blocked (which it does - I ran it on my machine).

Thank you very much

```
public class Deadlock {
    static class Friend {
       private final String name;
       public Friend(String name) {
          this.name = name;
       }
       public String getName() {
          return this.name;
       }
         public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
         System.out.format("%s: %s"
            + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
            this.name, bower.getName());
         bower.bowBack(this);
         }
         public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
            + " has bowed back to me!%n",
            this.name, bower.getName());
         }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         final Friend alphonse =
         new Friend("Alphonse");
         final Friend gaston =
         new Friend("Gaston");
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
           }).start();
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
           }).start();
      }
}
```

when running it - I get the following output:

Alphonse: Gaston  has bowed to me!

Gaston: Alphonse  has bowed to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `synchronized` keyword implicitly means a lock will be acquired upon entering the method or block. When it is used on a method, it is equivalent to this:

```
public void bow(Friend bower) {
    synchronized (this) {    
        System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
        bower.bowBack(this);
     }
 }
```

Only one thread at a time can acquire this lock, meaning that only one thread can run either `bow` or `bowBack` at a time since the lock is held by `this`.

Now with that in mind, here's one possible deadlock scenario in detail:

- Thread 1 calls `Alphonse.bow`
- Thread 1 acquires `Alphonse.lock`
- Thread 2 calls `Gaston.bow`
- Thread 2 acquires `Gaston.lock`
- Thread 1 calls `Gaston.bowBack`
- Thread 1 waits for `Gaston.lock` to be released because Thread 2 is still owning it
- Thread 2 calls `Alphonse.bowBack`
- Thread 2 waits for `Alphonse.lock` to be released because Thread is still owning it

Therefore, both threads are holding a lock that the other threads need to complete, and that's a deadlock!

Comment: Thanks @Dici, it takes off some shadow. Could you elaborate a bit more on the following explanation, specifically on: "_However here the two friends are trying to bow at each other simultaneously from two different threads. It is therefore likely that for bowing back, thread 2 needs to access bowBack's lock, which is the same as bow, however bow is still running in thread 1 and waiting for thread 2 to exit bow to acquire the lock in bowBack_" ?

Comment: I'll have to do that later as I need to go off doing something, but if something isn't clear let me know and I'll complete my answer later on :p Seems like your comment was incomplete

Comment: Dici, thank you very much for breaking it!! and of course for the (extremely!) fast reply !

Comment: No prob, I will remove the piece of text you found confusion, I had written it before I decide to add the detail scenario, which I find more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

- Thread 1: `alphonse.bow(gaston)`, so Thread 1 acquires the lock of alphonse to be able to call its synchronized method `bow`
- Thread 2: `gaston.bow(alphonse)`, so Thread 2 acquires the lock of gaston to be able to call its synchronized method `bow`
- Thread 1: `bower.bowBack(this);`, i.e. `gaston.bowBack(alphonse)`, so thread 1 needs to acquire the lock of gaston to be able to call its synchronized method `bowBack`. But thread 2 already has this lock, so thread 1 blocks, waiting until the lock is released by thread 2.
- Thread 2: `bower.bowBack(this);`, i.e. `alphonse.bowBack(gaston)`, so thread 2 needs to acquire the lock of alphonse to be able to call its synchronized method `bowBack`. But thread 1 already has this lock, so thread 2 blocks, waiting until the lock is released by thread 1.

You thus have a deadlock: both threads are waiting forever until the other one release a lock.

Comment: JB Nizet Thats a great explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are two objects and also that a `synchronized` method `bow` calls another synchronized method `bowBack` on an object that was passed as an argument.

So what happens there :

1. Thread 1 acquires instristic lock on `alphonse` object when calling `alphonse.bow()` method.
2. Thread 2 acquires instrictic lock on `gaston` object when calling `gaston.bow()` method.
3. Thread 1 tries to call `bower.bowBack(this);` where `bower` refers to `gaston` object. It will have to wait since another thread holds instrictic lock on `gaston` object.
4. Thread 2 tries to call `bower.bowBack(this);` where `bower` refers to `alphonse` object. It will have to wait since another thread holds instrictic lock on `alphonse` object.
5. Since both threads are waiting for a resource which is held by another one - we have a deadlock.

Of course when you try to run your program the deadlock might not appear. But there is a great possibility of it to appear so it should be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks michalk, your explanation revealed something new to me: if I understand correctly, syncronized provokes acquirement of a lock that is refering solely on the object and where it goes. And if the lock is not released - nothing can be done with the object. Did I get it right? One last question on this - how can the method release the lock on the object if does not need it anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You have two threads. Thread `A` is told to run `alphonse.bow(gastone)`, and thread `G` is told to run  `gaston.bow(alphonse)`.

Upon entering the `bow`, each thread acquires a lock. Thread `A` acquires `alphonse`'s lock, while thread `G` acquirels `gaston`'s lock.

Let's look at thread `A`. It acquired `alphonse`'s lock, performed the bow, and now 
it tries to run `gastone.bowBack(alphonse)`. To do that, it needs to acquire `gastone`'s lock.

However, `gastone`'s lock is held by thread `G`, which is doing the same thing - trying to acquire `alphonse`'s lock for a bow back.

The problem here is that the threads attempt to do this while still holding on to the original lock they acquired. Thread `A` is holding `alphonse`'s lock, and has not released it, and is now trying to get `gastone`'s lock. It cannot be released, because thread `G` is holding it while waiting for thread `A` to release its hold on `alphonse`'s lock.

The point here is that if you call another method while you are in a synchronized method, you're not releasing the locks you already have.

Comment: Hi RealSkeptic, thanks for the crystal clear explanation. There one thing that does not  get to me yet: suppose that we are in the situation you described - is there any piece of code we could right, in the locking method, to release the intrinsic lock? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @guyr79 Not in a synchronized method. You are simply not supposed to write code that does this sort of thing. This example is too artificial to propose a good solution, because it's not clear what the lock represents anyway. Do further research on deadlock prevention.

Comment: Got it @realSkeptic, and will keep on researching. Thank you very much!